# Matlab: calculate translation between two graphs

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

consider the following graphs:

[image]

All graphs represent measurements of a surface, but taken in different directions.

I would like to compute how much the blue graph(s) are shifted to the right compared to the red graph(s).
Is there a built-in function in MATLAB to achieve this? If not, how else could one approximate the "phase" shift?

Comment: Would correlation be what you are looking for (the `corr` function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xcorr` for a quick and dirty solution, presuming that the shifts are not too large and the sampling is equal:

```
[c lags] = xcorr(red,blue);
```

`c` is the actual correlations.  `lags` is the shifts made to the `blue` input before correlating it with `red`.

Therefore, `lags(c==max(c))` should tell you how much to shift `blue` to get the best match with `red`.

Comment: +1 To consider several blue and red graphs, you can compute the sum of red graphs one hand, the sum of the blue ones on the other, and then apply `xcorr`to those sums